# Find the best layout(grid) for a given size

Tags: c#, wpf, algorithm, layout

I've a WPF custom panel, in which I want to layout several elements (in my case 12, but ideally I would like to find an algorithm that work for all) all with the same min width/height. The layout is a Grid, but I can choose  the number of column/rows I want.

I would like to find a way to decide how many columns and how many rows I create, depending on the ratio of the window.

If the sub-elements had 1/1 ratio it would be easier; I would only have to compute the ratio for the possible layouts (admitting I've 12 sub-elements: 12/1, 6/2, 4/3, 3/4, 2/6, 1/12) and check which one is the closer to the panel width/height ratio.

But in my real case, I could set my sub-items twice as high as wide, so I'm a little bit lost on how to compute this? I guess I need to take their "ideal size", and then do some math between, but I don't know how.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation and Unit Tests, I think I found a solution. In fact I don't need the width/height but just their ratio, same for elements.

I've the following class representing a Layout:

```
public class Layout : IEquatable<Layout>
{
    public int RowCount { get; }
    public int ColumnCount { get;  }
    public double Ratio { get; }

    public Layout(int rowCount, int columnCount)
    {
        RowCount = rowCount;
        ColumnCount = columnCount;
        Ratio = (float)rowCount/columnCount;
    }
}
```

And I've done the following to get the best layout:

```
public class LayoutAdapter
{
    public Layout ComputeBestGridLayout(int elementsCount, double elementRatio, double panelRatio)
    {
        IEnumerable<Layout> possibleLayouts = GetPossibleLayouts(elementsCount);
        return FindBestLayouts(possibleLayouts, elementRatio, panelRatio);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Layout> GetPossibleLayouts(int elementCounts)
    {
        //TODO Increment "elementsCounts", because maybe with some hole we will have a better match for the ratio
        List<Layout> acceptedResults =new List<Layout>();
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 <= elementCounts; i1++)
        {
            double rest2 = elementCounts%((double) i1);
            if (rest2 == 0)
            {
                int i2 = elementCounts/i1;
                acceptedResults.Add(new Layout(i1,i2));
            }
        }
        return acceptedResults;
    }


    private Layout FindBestLayouts(IEnumerable<Layout> possibleLayouts, double elementRatio, double panelRatio)
    {
        Layout closestLayout = null;
        double minDiff=Double.MaxValue;


        foreach (Layout possibleLayout in possibleLayouts)
        {
            double currentDiff = Math.Abs((panelRatio/ elementRatio) - possibleLayout.Ratio);
            if (currentDiff < minDiff)
            {
                minDiff = currentDiff;
                closestLayout = possibleLayout;
            }
        }
        return closestLayout;
    }

}
```